# Replacing a derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

If I want to calculate e.g. $\frac{dr(t)}{dt}$ then in Mathematica we can write e.g. ,

```
answer = D[r[t],t]
```

This outputs `r'[t]` which is fine. Now, if I then want to replace `r'[t]` in answer with some different symbol, e.g. `r1` how would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `D[r[t], t] /. r'[t] -> r1`?

Comment: You can also do `r /: Derivative[1][r] = r1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do it by /. is shortest way to subtitute or replace variables

```
answer = D[r[t], t] /.r'[t]->r1
```

this give you r1

or just keep your answer as its then put as follow

```
answer = D[r[t], t]

answer /. r'[t] -> r1
```